# rediccionar a una pagina despues de realizar una insert

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

buenas tardes me pueden colaborar que tengo que agregar en el codigo para una vez que realice la insert me redireccione a la pagina index.php  donde esta el formulario insert y me muestre el mensaje que aparece en el codigo despues de realizar el insert , me esta realizando la inserccion pero me queda en la pagina del controlador

```
public function addUsuarios($Name,$Last_Name,$Email,$User,$Pass,$Perfil,$Estado)
        {
            $statement= $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,last_name,email,usuario,password,perfil,estado) VALUES 
            (:name,:last_name,:email,:user,:pass,:perfil,:estado)");
            //encriptación de clave usando algortimo de encriptacion hash
            $Pass_cifrado=password_hash($Pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $statement->bindParam(':name',$Name);
            $statement->bindParam(':last_name',$Last_Name);
            $statement->bindParam(':email',$Email);
            $statement->bindParam(':user',$User);
            $statement->bindParam(':pass',$Pass_cifrado);
            $statement->bindParam(':perfil',$Perfil);
            $statement->bindParam(':estado',$Estado);
            if($statement->execute() && $statement->rowCount()>0){
                $r=array("add"=>true,"msg"=>"se han agregado los datos:".$statement->rowCount());
              }else{
                  $r=array("msg"=>"No se agregaron los datos");
              }
              echo json_encode($r);
        }
```

```js
function NuevoUsuario(Name,Last_name,Email,User,Pass,Perfil,Estado) {
    var Name=$('#nombre').val();
    var Last_name=$('#apellido').val();
    var Email=$('#email').val();
    var User=$('#usuario').val();
    var Pass=$('#pass').val();
    var Perfil=$('#perfil').val();
    var Estado=$('#estado').val();
    var mData={
        Name:Name,
        Last_name:Last_name,
        Email:Email,
        User:User,
        Pass:Pass,
        Perfil:Perfil,
        Estado:Estado
    };
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"../Controller/add.php",
        data:mData,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(r){
            if(r.add){
                swal.fire(
                    'Se ha Registro Usuario',
                    'success'
                )+r.msg;
            }else{
                swal.fire(
                    'Error de registro',
                    'error'
                )+r.msg;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

codigo html lo estoy llamando

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top:3%; width:450px; background:#8B8B83; border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px; ">
     <h3>Registrar Usuario</h3>
     <hr>
     <form >
      <label for="nombre"><b>Nombre :</b> </label> <br>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control"> <br>
      <label for="apellido"><b>Apellido :</b></label> <br>
      <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Apellido" class="form-control"> <br>
      <label for="usuario"><b>Correo Electronico:</b></label> <br>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Correo Electronico" class="form-control"> <br>
      <label for="usuario">Usuario :</label> <br>
      <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Usuario" class="form-control"> <br>
      <label for="pass">Password :</label> <br>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"> <br>
      <label for="estado">Perfil:</label> <br>
       <select name="perfil" id="perfil" class="form-control">
           <option value="0">Seleccione perfil de usuario</option>
           <option value="1">admnistrador</option>
           <option value="2">docente</option>
           <option value="2">estudiante</option>
       </select> <br>
      
      <label for="estado">Estado:</label> <br>
       <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
           <option value="0">Seleccione estado del usuario</option>
           <option value="1">Activo</option>
           <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
       </select> <br>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="NuevoUsuario();" style="margin-bottom: 5%;">Registrar</button>
     </form>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar agregar una función `then` para que luego de mostrar el `Swal.fire` realice la dirección, algo así:

```js
function NuevoUsuario(Name,Last_name,Email,User,Pass,Perfil,Estado) {
    var Name=$('#nombre').val();
    var Last_name=$('#apellido').val();
    var Email=$('#email').val();
    var User=$('#usuario').val();
    var Pass=$('#pass').val();
    var Perfil=$('#perfil').val();
    var Estado=$('#estado').val();
    var mData={
        Name:Name,
        Last_name:Last_name,
        Email:Email,
        User:User,
        Pass:Pass,
        Perfil:Perfil,
        Estado:Estado
    };
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"../Controller/add.php",
        data:mData,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(r){
            if(r.add){
              Swal.fire({
              position: 'top-end',
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'Se ha registrado el usuario',
              showConfirmButton: false,
              html: r.msg,
              timer: 1500}).then(function(){location.href='tu_URL';});
          } else{
              Swal.fire({
              position: 'top-end',
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Error de registro',
              html: r.msg
            });
            return false
          }
        }
    });

}
```

Ojala sea lo que buscas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una redirección y que esta funcione correctamente, para este caso debes hacerla en el método AJAX ya que es él que esta manejando el hilo de petición.

```
function NuevoUsuario(Name,Last_name,Email,User,Pass,Perfil,Estado) {
  var Name=$('#nombre').val();
  var Last_name=$('#apellido').val();
  var Email=$('#email').val();
  var User=$('#usuario').val();
  var Pass=$('#pass').val();
  var Perfil=$('#perfil').val();
  var Estado=$('#estado').val();
  var mData={
    Name:Name,
    Last_name:Last_name,
    Email:Email,
    User:User,
    Pass:Pass,
    Perfil:Perfil,
    Estado:Estado
  };
  $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"../Controller/add.php",
    data:mData,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(r){
        if(r.add){
            swal.fire(
                'Se ha Registro Usuario',
                'success'
            )+r.msg;

            //Redireccionamiento
            window.location.replace("https://es.stackoverflow.com/");

        }else{
            swal.fire(
                'Error de registro',
                'error'
            )+r.msg;
        }
    }
  });

}
```

Espero ser de ayuda

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que hiciste tu petición Ajax, procesa los datos, termina de procesar y entra al success

```
success: function(datos){
        //alert(msg);
        $("#modalFinalizarResguardo").modal('hide'); //Aquí oculta el modal desde donde yo llamo el Ajax.
        swal("Finalizaci\u00F3n de revisi\u00F3n Exitosa!","Haga Clic para Cerrar","success"); // Alerta swal para indicar que se ha procesado correctamente
        console.log("Alert Callback");  
        window.location = 'la_ruta_de_tu_pagina.php;// Ésto invoca la solicitud de retornar a alguna pagina,en mi caso me regresa dos paginas hacia atrás 

        },
```

Tienes que colocar la instrucción antes de que salga del succes,si no, no funciona , a mi en lo particular así me ha funcionado correctamente la cantidad de veces que he hecho la prueba o le test del sistema.